# How can I make my tkinter settings Class update my function Class every time the settings are changed?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, application-settings

So I have something akin to this set up:

```
class FrameBase(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        ## Create 3 windows, the front, settings and the function


class Front(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self,parent,control):
         ## Has buttons to navigate between settings and the function
```

And my problem is that my function does not update its values that are picked up from settings-Class after **init** has parsed through once. How they communicate at the moment is roughly this:

```
class Front(tk.Frame):
    def __init(self,parent,control):
         settings = Settings(self, self) ## (self, self) required because of the infrastructure as far as I can tell. 
                                         ## It does bring the setting values fine so that's not a problem in and of itself.
         settingvalues = settings.bring_settings()




    def magic()
          #Does magic based on the settingvalues


class Settings(tk.Frame):
       def __init(self,parent,control):
             # user can change settings 



       def bring_settings(self):
             # return setting values
```

And the problem is that basically I don't know how I can make the function request/take the setting values either every time the settings are changed, the function window is opened or every x interval (this one would probably be heaviest?).

Comment: use [The Variable Classes (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

Comment: I am using StringVar already in Settings, but now the problem I'm encountering is that when in my solution to the problem of updating the settings to the function, every time I call the class settings, tkinter enters an infinite loop with "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable".

Comment: use print() to check your variables. It seems you did `variable = None` and now you try to do `variable()` which means `None()`. Maybe you forgot to use `variable.set()`

Comment: You're right in that it requires a variable somewhere, but the breakpoint of my code is when I'm handling two button commands with one, specifically when I try to update the settings onto the function. [Here](http://pastebin.com/3iYFMpE6) is a pastebin (But it's not in English so visual cues is the best it gives unless I start translating it) that shows that combined_func is the breakpoint

Comment: you have problem with arguments in `kaksikomentoa()`. Use `print(funktiot)` to see values in variables  (using `print()` is very usefull method to find problem). You send two argumets - `lambda` and `None`. Maybe you create `lambda` in wrong way in button `Pelaa"` and you need `()` - `lambda:(function1, function2)`. Now you have `kaksikomentoa(lambda:function1, function2)` which means `kaksikomentoa( (lambda:function1), function2)`, not `kaksikomentoa( lambda:(function1, function2) )` nor `kaksikomentoa( lambda:function1, lambda:function2 )`

Comment: My päivitäasetukset() -funktion is the culprit as it seems like I'm still unable to change the settings of my Pelaa -class using the function for some reason. So to sum it up, my core problem seems to be that I an unable to change the StringVar of my child Class using a generic function

Comment: now you have problem because `päivitäasennukset(parent,ohjain)` returns `None` and then you have `command=kaksikomentoa(lambda: ohjain.näytä_ikkuna("Pelaa"), None)` and this `None` inside `kaksikomentoa` is use as function name - `None()`.

Comment: use `()` in `lambda` to get `lambda:(fun1, fun2)` instead of `lambda:fun1, fun2` and get `kaksikomentoa( lambda: (ohjain.näytä_ikkuna("Pelaa"), päivitäasennukset(parent,ohjain)) )` - it solve at least problem with error message.